# Ajax and PHP debug

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Building a script that once a date is selected in a datepicker calendar, it uses ajax to post the selected date in a php script;

in the success of that ajax call, it uses another ajax call to post the same selected date to another php script and displays that in the page.

Did some research around and this seemed to be the best solution for what I try to do.

The script is the following:

```
<script> //for the events
    jQuery(function($) {

  $(".date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
      $(this).change();
    }
  }).on("change", function() {
    display("Got change event from field");
    // call next ajax function

    var mydate = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'boxes_script.php',
        data: ({dates: mydate}),
            dataType : 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.caixas').html(data);
            alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'events_script.php',
                data: ({dates1: mydate}),
                    dataType : 'html',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.results-ajax').html(data);
                alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
    </script>
```

**This is the code being used atm. Got some updates because of the feedback given here, but the solution still hasn't worked 100%**

There's a problem on it and I think it's because the second Ajax call is inside of a success Ajax.

*The problem is the following*:
The data is being posted in the php scripts, which run like how they should.
The array gets populated with the right information.
The

> $('.caixas').html(data);

works fine and displays data from 'boxes_script.php' there.

The

> $('.results-ajax').html(data);

receives 100% of the data being sent from 'events_script.php' but for any weird reason, doesn't append it to the page..

I can see the data in alert messages and it's the right data being sent to the browser.

***Why isn't that data being appended to the page?***

This is the php code for 'events_script.php':

```
<?php
include 'config/config.php';
include 'libraries/database.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  print_r($_POST);
  echo $_POST[dates1];

    $dias= $_POST[dates1];
    $mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dias));
    echo $mysql_date;

   //Make database query
   $sql = "***";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $image = $row['Company_Logo'];
        $myArray = json_decode($image, true);
        $event=$row['eventID'];
        echo '<div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">
                          <div id="'.$dias.'"  class="container day-events">
                                <div class="row event-list">
                                    <div class="event-list-time col-md-3 col-sm-3 center" style="background-image:url('.$myImage = $myArray[0]['name'].');">
                                        <p class="event-list-start-time">'.$row['Start_Date'].'</p>
                                        <hr class="event-list-time-divider">
                                        <p class="event-list-end-time">'.$row['End_Date'].'</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="event-list-info col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                                        <h2 class="event-list-name">'.$row['Event_Name'].'</h2>
                                        <p>Organized by <span class="event-list-organizer"><a href="mini-about.php?$company='.$row['Ref_ID'].'">'.$row['Company_Name'].'</a></span></p>
                                        <p class="event-list-description">'.$row['Event_Description'].'</p>
                                        <a href="mini-single-event.php?event='.$event.'"><button type="button" class="btn more-info-list">More Information</button></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                        </div>';
        }} else { echo 'No results found.'; }
}
?>
```

**Note:** no errors were found in the error log. The network gives status 200.

**The data can be seen sent to the browser here:**

[image]

**The first part of the data is being appended to the browser, as you can see in the images.**

[image]

***Why is not working everything?***

Comment: I believe in the second ajax call, `this` doesn't refer to your `$(".date")` anymore but rather the first ajax call

Comment: based mostly on you're i'd say that in the second ajax you are referring to This that is out of scope for javascript in that moment. you need to either use the data returned from the 1°st ajax operation or you can put the value inside another variables and then use it whenever you want.

Comment: You can go two ways 1) update so that `boxes_scripts.php` returns the date back and then it will be in the 2nd ajax `data`. 2) Call your `events_script.php` script in `boxes_scripts.php` and remove the 2nd call all together. I would go for #2.

Comment: @nerdlyist problem is that the results get displayed in different areas of the html. The 2nd would not work

Comment: You can split a data object over as many areas as you want. If you have `{"message1" : "Foo", "message2": "bar"}` just use the selector for where each message should go. If you gave a bit more I could help ie what the php is doing and where the result is going.

Comment: @tiagoperes - it is great that you have solved it. However, we do not overwrite questions with answers here, since that is confusing for new readers. Would you be able to copy your answer to an answer box below, where it says "Your Answer"? I have rolled back, but your solution can be found [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42070073/revisions).

Comment: please post your php code, so we can look if maybe the communication between php and js is wrong

Comment: @halfer check now, just updated the message, there's a problem

Comment: @Sysix just updated now the code

Comment: Is that the old problem, or a new one? If it is a new one, and if it also invalidates the answers you have already been given, then please roll back that change and ask a new question.

Comment: it's the same problem, the answer didn't fullfil 100% of the requirements

Comment: Were the requirements in the question at the start? If they were not, they are new requirements.

Comment: @halfer 'Building a script that once a date is selected in a datepicker calendar, it uses ajax to post the selected date in a php script;

in the success of that ajax call, it uses another ajax call to post the same selected date to another php script and displays that in the page.'

Thought that was obvious

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstood me. Has your substantial update invalidated any of the answers you have already been given? Were they good answers for the problem as was stated at the time?

Comment: No, the answers just basically contribute to make the code go closer to its purpose. Specially the one from Chetan Gawai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was what fixed the problem and made the following final result:

[image]

**Old:**

```
<div class="row events-tabs">
     <div class="container" data-example-id="togglable-tabs"> 
         <ul class="nav nav-pills center caixas" id="myTabs" role="tablist">
          </ul> 
         <div class="results-ajax tab-content" id="myTabContent">
         </div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

**New:**

```
 <div class="row events-tabs">
      <div class="container" data-example-id="togglable-tabs"> 
           <ul class="nav nav-pills center caixas" id="myTabs" role="tablist">
           </ul> 
           <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="results-ajax"></div>
           </div> 
      </div>
 </div>
```

So, basically **using results-ajax as class of an own div** fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`data1: ({dates1: this.value})`

to

```
data: ({dates1: this.value})
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the POST value on your server side script ?

Comment: Sure It's probably not your main issue, but you can't name the data property "data1", it will be not recognize by jQuery.

Comment: in boxes_script.php:
$dias= $_POST[dates];

in events_script.php:
$dias= $_POST[dates1];

Comment: Maybe "this" referencing the wrong scope. create a variable before the first ajax call (var dateToPost = this.value) and use dateToPost in your ajax properties in each ajax calls (data: ({dates1: dateToPost})

Answer (score 1):

```
var mydate = this.value; // add before the 1st ajax call
```

change -

```
data1: ({dates1: mydate})
```

Comment: where is that variable mydate gonna be at?

Comment: before the 1st `ajax` call