# jQuery Ajax Store Data to database by multiple checkbox check

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have multiple checkbox below

[image]

Demo can be found [here](https://jsbin.com/cosebiqilo/edit?html,output).

We can see on above image, if I check some of that checkbox and then I click Update then it will show the checkbox value with each ID.

And now I want to store it to database. Here is my table:

```
ID | CHKSTATUS
1  | update
2  | create
2  | delete
```

I need to store it using jQuery Ajax to PHP

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnUpdate').click(function(){
    var cb = [];
    $.each($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function(){
      cb.push($(this).data('id') + ' -> ' +$(this).data('tipe'));
    });
    $('#status').val(cb.join("\n"));
  });

  $.ajax(
  {

  })
});
```

Anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Check this link, it's explaining how I pass the data from JS to PHP and then to JS again.
In your case, the PHP would post to the DB.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070073/ajax-and-php-debug

Hope this helps

Comment: First, create a variable in JS with the data you want. Then, use Post method. Then, grab that data in the PHP file. Then you can use it for whatever you want

Comment: @tiagoperes I saw that post, but I think it's different with my case. Multiple checkbox

Comment: it would be better if you can give me an example of my case

Answer (score 0):

The process you need can be broken down into the following steps:

**Client side:**

```
var mydate = (the data you want to pass to the PHP file); // create a variable with the data you need
    $.ajax({ //start an ajax call
        type: "POST", //post method
        url: 'script.php', //define which php file you want to post to
        data: ({dates: mydate}), //define which data you want to pass to
            dataType : 'html', //the type of the data
        success: function(data) { //what to do after being posted
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

**Server side:**
Then, once in the PHP file (script.php), this is how you get the data:

```
$dias= $_POST[dates];
```

Because you also want to write things to the DB, you need to connect to the DB.
Do a normal PHP connection:

```
// variables
$servername = "server";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
//Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//Make database query
$sql = "***"; // this is how you're going to use the variable in the query: '".$dias."'
//Connect    
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```